# Wampserver cannot start after adding a LoadFile in httpd.conf on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, wamp

The system is `Windows 8.1 Pro` and there is `wampserver 2.4` installed in it ; there is also a `PostgreSQL` database inside the computer. I want to add this line inside the `httpd.conf` of Apache : `LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/libpq.dll"`

The problem is that when I start `WampServer` then it does not reach to the green color ( at the status bar of the computer ). So I replaced `Program Files` to `Program Files (x86)` but it is same problem ! So how to fix it ?

Comment: What do the server error logs say?

Answer (score 0):

The libpq.dll is not an Apache module and therefore cannot be loaded into Apache.

It should suffice to copy this dll into the

`\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin`

folder.